# Android tab bar with different fragments and different action bar icons

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

### Problem Description and Question

I'm using tab activity with action bar. In the HOME tab I have `GridView` which contains some items, like it is shown in the image below (Hot Lines, Taxi, Restaurants etc)

[image]

Wen user click on the items in the grid view I want my application to take following actions:

- Change icon of application to grid view item image on which I pressed.
- Change the test near the icon
- Add standard back button near icon, which will go back to grid view screen.
- Change the tab fragment to the one which I specify.

Like it is shown in the image below:

[image]

As I never deal with this kind of problems can you please give me example or share some link with me of how I can do this? and can I do this at all?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
[Android studio - is possible to add tabs pointing to fragments from designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785570/android-studio-is-possible-to-add-tabs-pointing-to-fragments-from-designer/25785688#25785688)
It is not exactly what you want, but a good start. If you are willing to put a bit of work in it, you should be able to get what you want. If you have a basic Frame to work with and more specific problems with this matter I will gladly help you out ^^

John

Answer (score 1):

The first link you can check is [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279981/how-can-i-change-action-bar-actions-dynamically).

And you should read more about [**ActionBar**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

The last thing is it's better if you google it first and try to write a code and when you got stuck somewhere share your code with us and ask for help.

Comment: I did that way I googled then I try to write some code and after that I put question here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use actionbarsherlock library for it.

use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` and `TabWidget` in the xml as shown below :

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    style="@style/yourstyle"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        style="@style/realtabFrameContentStyle" />


       <TabWidget
          android:id="@android:id/tabs"
         style="@style/yourtabstyle" />

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Use SherlockFragmentActivity for showing the tabs.

In the activities code use following code (preferably in a function) to set the ctionbar icon and text :

```
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_action_barlayout);


((TextView) (activity.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title))).setText("your title");

        ImageView homeButton = ((ImageView) (activity.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.your_icon)));
        homeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourHOmeActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
        ActionBar mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        mActionBar.show();
```

then call this function with your icon and your text in your fragments `onResume()` method.

Comment: I prefer not to use Action ActionbarSherlock

Comment: In that case create your custom layout with textview and imageview,  then set this custom layout to your actionbar and then change the icon on tab bar click event.

Comment: Please refer for further details : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html